# Not possible to override js/misc/ajax.js using hook_js_alter in Bootstrap theme

Tags: 7, hooks, ajax, theming

I am trying to specify another custom `ajax.js` file in place of `js/misc/ajax.js` using **hook_js_alter(&$variables)** but with no success. Upon inspection of the `&$variables` array, my target file `js/misc/ajax.js` does not appear there at all and thus it is not possible to override it using **HOOK_js_alter(&$variables)**

Any idea how to override that file?

Comment: Drupal doesn't have a `/js` folder, you probably mean `misc/ajax.js`

Comment: @Clive `js/misc/ajax.js` is found inside the Bootstrap's base theme directory. It defines two Ajax functions that override the corresponding ones in Drupal core. I need to override those two functions once more inside my sub-theme folder.